# Exiting batch with `EXIT /B X` where X>=1 acts as if command completed successfully when using && or || operators between batch calls

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exit, errorlevel

I'm trying to chain a series of .bat files using the `EXIT /B X` command to return success or failure and `&&` and `||` for conditional running of the next .bat (e.g. `a.bat && b.bat`).

Regardless of whether I call `EXIT /B 0` or anything else to end a.bat, `a.bat && b.bat` will call b.bat afterward. My understanding is that `EXIT /B 0` should set `ERRORLEVEL=0`, which is success, so the `&&` should continue. The counterpoint to this is that calling `EXIT /B 1` should set `ERRORLEVEL=1` which is failure, so the `&&` should stop. What am I missing here?

Trivialized example:

For non-batch commands, acting as expected:

```
C:\> echo test|findstr test>NUL && echo yes
yes

C:\> echo test|findstr test>NUL || echo yes

C:\> echo test|findstr nope>NUL && echo yes

C:\> echo test|findstr nope>NUL || echo yes
yes
```

Using `EXIT /B` always sees a.bat as successful:

```
C:\> echo @EXIT /B 0 > a.bat

C:\> a.bat && echo yes
yes

C:\> a.bat || echo yes

C:\> echo @EXIT /B 1 > a.bat

C:\> a.bat && echo yes
yes

C:\> a.bat || echo yes
```

How can I exit from a.bat so that `a.bat && b.bat` and `a.bat || b.bat` behave as expected?

All commands are run in cmd.exe on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: I have never seen those operators used in batch files before. I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing. Edit: and I can't find any documentation about it, so I'm surprised you haven't seen any syntax errors.

Comment: The usage of these operators is detailed here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @JordanEvens I get `the page you requested cannot be found` (but three upvotes suggest, it's just me...) Another description is on [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

Comment: Can't find a replacement right away on the microsoft site, but the wayback machine seems to have a copy of the original: https://web.archive.org/web/20170220015700/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you ask me, exit codes in batch files are broken for this exact reason, but there is a hacky workaround you can use. As the last line of your batch file, use:

```
@%COMSPEC% /C exit 1 >nul
```

Since this is an actual process that is started you get a real process exit code and && and || will work.

Comment: Although it's a bit weird to use this for exiting, it provides the expected behaviour when other things call the batch so it makes the most sense to use this instead of modifying everything else to use calls.

Comment: I was confused for a bit, so this is just a note for others that you literally need that to be the last line of the file.  It won't actually exit the batch, just set the error code.  Calling `EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%` directly after it doesn't always seem to work either.  The only reliable method I found was to use `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :end` and have a label `:end` just before the last line with `%COMSPEC% /C EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%>NUL`

Comment: Could this issue be related to a [problem I encountered recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418960/dos-inline-if-test-for-errorlevel-without-use-of-delayed-expansion)?

Answer (score 12):

It works as it should when using **call** to execute batch scripts containing an exit statement:

```
C:\>echo @EXIT /B 1 > a.bat

C:\>call a.bat && echo yes

C:\>call a.bat || echo yes
yes
```

By the way, it says *wrongly* on *[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call)*:

> Call has no effect at the command prompt
>   when it is used outside of a script or batch
>   file.

Comment: Call has also an effect for this: set var=%%var%%<enter>call call call echo %var%

Comment: CALL command was there to address a historical mistake in the DOS ages: the old COMMAND.COM interpreter considers batch file command be launched differently than external programs (.com or .exe). For batch file command, the shell stops the batch file it's running and loads the new batch. (Think of this as similar to `exec foo.sh` in Unix shell - the old script halts and launches new one.) To address the cases where the users/scripts want to continue execution after new script finishes, CALL command was introduced. The peculiar behavior of batch file command remains for compatibility.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `start /wait` you can also use this in a very simple Windows application (written in C#) called by DOS batch files like so:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Environment.ExitCode = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Then the application can be called by your DOS batch file and evaluate the result. i.e.

```
c:> start /wait SetRC 1
c:> if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto abort
```

NOTE: the `/wait` is not necessary in a batch file.

You could pass in the return code you want as an argument to your program.cs and get it out this way guaranteed.

Comment: there's no `start` command and `%errorlevel%` in DOS. [Windows cmd and MS-DOS are very different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting `Errorlevel=0` with because you are indeed executing a.bat (regardless of the return code).

You would fail the check if `a.bat` did not exist. [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) is the only way I know to pull in the environment from `a.bat`.